# Jquery change div background inside tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to get this to work for quite some time now.

I am looking for a way to change the background of a div inside a tr onclick with jquery.

What I mean by this is that when the tr (which is named by class) is clicked, then the div with a class name (that is inside the tr) changes color.

The problem that I have been having is that I can set the color of all the divs with the specified class name but not just the one that I clicked it's tr.

I would think the code would look something like this:

```
   $('.backpack_row').click( function(){
  if ($(this).css('background-color') != 'rgb(255, 255, 204)')
  {
      $(this .divClassname).css('background-color', '#000000');
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffcc');
  }
  else
  {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
      $(this .divClassname).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
  }
```

});

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="backpack_row"><td><div class="divClassname"></div></td><td>Other Stuff</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Can you show us your html please. Also instead of checking for the specific background color, i would check against the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your code. A JQuery selector call should be in this format:

- `$("selector")`
- `$("selector", context)` (where context is `this`, in this case)

---

```
   $('.backpack_row').click( function(){
  if ($(this).css('background-color') != 'rgb(255, 255, 204)')
  {
      $(".divClassname", this).css('background-color', '#000000');
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffcc');
  }
  else
  {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
      $(".divClassname", this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
  }
```

Comment: One other thing, is there anyway to use a background image instead of color for when i am setting the .divClassname to black?

Comment: That's why it wasn't working. I was using only single quotes instead of double quotes. Thanks

Comment: Quotes doesn't matter. You were probably using `background-color` instead of `background` or `background-image`.

Comment: Hello, I just realized that this is not working for me in IE 9 is there a reason or do you think that it might just be the code around it? Thanks Ian

Comment: Use `alert($(this).css('background-color'))`. What color format do you get?

Comment: Yea thanks i realized that in ie they don't put spaces in between the rgb color format. so i just put an made the if statement look for either format.

Comment: This code should work now, and in future crappy releases of IE: `if(!/^\s*rgb(\s*255\s*,\s*255\s*,\s*204\s*)\s*$/i.test($(this).css("background-color"))`

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are a bit off, and you're making this harder for yourself. Instead of checking for background colors, check for class existence:

```
$(".backpack_row").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("highlighted")) {
        $(this).find(".divClassname").addClass("divHighlighted");
        $(this).addClass("highlighted");
    } else {
        $(this).find(".divClassname").removeClass("divHighlighted");
        $(this).removeClass("highlighted");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.backpack_row').click( function(){
  if ($(this).css('background-color') != 'rgb(255, 255, 204)')
  {
      $(this).find(.divClassname).css('background-color', '#000000');
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffcc');
  }
  else
  {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
      $(this).find(.divClassname).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
  }
});
```

You need to use the `el.find()` function. It will find an element based on a selector within the `el`.
For documentation, [here](http://api.jquery.com/find/)